# RegEx test method returns false when it should be true

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've tested the three of the regex's on http://www.regexpal.com/ and they are what I need, but when doing a regex test 2 of them return false (BTC and CAD) and only the Bitcoin address seems to work (you may test with this wallet below).

> 13dHNxtbckAFM4PzdBqWgymFJmcv3Yzi32

https://jsfiddle.net/ps2fj1ff/1
(all the relevant code is in the html section)

```
    var regWallet = new RegExp("^[13][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{25,34}$");
    var regBTC = new RegExp("^\d*\.\d*$");
    var regCAD = new RegExp("^\d+(\.(\d{2}))?$");

    $('#button1').on('click', function() {

        var btcCheck = $('#amount_btc').val();  

        if (regBTC.test(btcCheck)) {

        } else {
            alert("Invalid BTC value!");
        }

        var cadCheck = $('#amount_cad').val();  

        if (regCAD.test(cadCheck)) {

        } else {
            alert("Invalid CAD value!");
        }

        var walletCheck = $('#wallet').val();
        if (regWallet.test(walletCheck)) {

        } else {
            alert("Invalid Bitcoin address, please make sure you've entered a valid address!");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that in `var regBTC = new RegExp("^\d*\.\d*$");` the `\` is used to escape the character so if you `console.log(regBTC)` you will see it as `^d*.d*$`.

To prevent this you will have to double escape it: `var regBTC = new RegExp("^\\d*\\.\\d*$");`

Or better yet use `/` instead: `var regBTC = /^\d*\.\d*$/;`

The same goes for the other regex too.

(I initially thought single quote would work too, but apparently not in javascript)

Comment: `new RegExp(/.../)` is redundant, just use`/.../`

Comment: true enough, I always try to change as little code as the OP as possible. but I think I shouldn't include redundancies.

Comment: good point. But I also think there is value in showing OP a better way, so they form better habits, and think about things like redundancy beyond the question they are asking.

Comment: Interesting! used the "/" and it all works great now! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
var regBTC = /^\d*\.\d*$/;
var regCAD = /^\d+(\.(\d{2}))$/;
```

It's cleaner and more readable as most editors will give you regexp syntax highlighting in this format.

There really isn't any good reason to use `new RegExp` which forces you to write the expression as a string, which forces you to use confusing escapes, when there is a proper regular expression syntax built into JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your input.